# Insure TLS 1.2 protocol for references

Tags: tls1.2

I will try to keep this general, as I am seeking a general answer.
When I open the properties window of one of the references in my project in Visual Studio I see this runtime version: v4.0.30319
This reference is used in a project where the target framework is .NET Framework 4.7.1. And it works fine.

My project is communicating with a database, and I want to make sure that this communication will be utilizing the TLS version 1.2 protocol. As I understand it, this can be insured by having the project targeted against .NET 4.7 or above.

Here is my question: if I have a project with a reference, which have a target framework that is lower than .NET 4.7, will this ruin my goal of using a TLS protocol of version 1.2?

How can I make sure that my reference is up to snuff? The runtime version written above, is not suggesting that this reference has a .NET Framework of 4.7 or above, or does it?